# Ruby extension in C, LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my own computer I compiled a Ruby extension writen in C. Then I added `require 'mytest/mytest'` to my controller and it works. Then I moved the files to the server and when I start Mongrel I have the message that:

```
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - {path_to_file}/mytest.so (LoadError)
```

If I follow that path there is a file `mytest.so`.

The permissions on `mytest.so` are set to 0777 and full path is checked, still the same.

can not recompile becouse i don't have gcc on production serv.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably different architecture, i.e. you had i386, and this is x86_64. Check with `uname -a` and `file mytest.so`

Comment: I have the same architecture.

Comment: Try to use full path (the error hints about this) and check permissions.

Comment: Let me get this straight - you put your `mytest.so` into lib/mytest inside your rails app, and then you're using `require 'mytest/mystest'` in your controller? I'd exactly this kind of setup, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you're probably going to need to recompile that binary extension--you can check for dependencies with the ldd command